# Как ходить и вверх и вниз?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Начал писать 2d игру на Unity. Изучаю движение через джостик(для андроида). Всё хорошо, двигается вправо-влево. Но не могу понять, что нужно сделать, чтобы объект двигался ещё и вверх и вниз.

Вот мой код:

```
    public Joystick joystick;

    private int speed = 4;

    private float moveInput;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        moveInput = joystick.Horizontal;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, 0);
    }
```

UPD:
Благодаря ответу, сделаю правку. Вот что я добавил:

```
    private float moveInput1;


        moveInput1 = joystick.Vertical;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, moveInput1 * speed);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ммм...
Опрашивать `joystick.Vertical;` и задавать второй компонент скорости?